# AnyLogic: How to set pedestrian comfortable speed beyond the range

Tags: anylogic

I got the problem of the pedestrian library. I would like to use the pedestrian library to simulate the behavior of the vehicle, therefore, I would like to set the comfortable speed of the agent to be, say 70km/h. However, there is an error saying the speed has to be within [0mps, 10mps]. Is there any way to set whatever speed I want?

Thank you,

Jiannan

Answer (score 0):

First why don't you use the road traffic library? But you must have your reasons.

You can't change the maximum speed value, but what you can do, which is not a very elegant solution, but a solution nonetheless, is to change the time scale of your model. There is no direct option for that, so you basically have to create your own clock that runs your way.

So for instance, if you want your car to move at 20mps, you choose 10 mps as the comfortable speed and you have the transformation customTime(time())=0.5*time(), where custom time is your own function.

So every time 1 second passes in the simulation, in your custom clock only 0.5 seconds will pass... You just have to take care of the statistics you are collecting so they fit your time scale. 
Also, you will have to change everything according to your clock in your model, because Anylogic will continue showing you things in normal seconds.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi Felip, thank you very much! Actually, I want my car to avoid obstacles, and maybe not moving straightly along the road (just like the pedestrian does), that's why I didn't use road traffic library. Do you know any method to do this? Thanks, Jiannan.

Comment: yes... you can use intersections in the traffic road where the obstacles are and forbid for the car to go straight.